# How to match a documentElement ID by finding the documentElement Name?

Tags: javascript, loops, dom

So on a website every time you refresh it the ID of a specific element changes but the name of it stays the same. I want to find the name and then match it with the document ID that was in the same document. I was thinking of running a loop but I dont know how to do it. This is how the html looks:

```html
<input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="
    value: value,
    valueUpdate: 'keyup',
    hasFocus: focused,
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        'aria-describedby': getDescriptionId(),
        'aria-required': required,
        'aria-invalid': error() ? true : 'false',
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled
    }" name="firstname" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" id="N6YFA53">
```

I want to match the name "firstname" with the id and then change the value of it because the id changes each time i refresh the page.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is not so clear to me, can you put more clarification on it?

Comment: Please give a concrete example of the expected input (the HTML) and output of the code you are trying to build.

Comment: What's the ultimate problem you want to solve? People get obsessed with using IDs for everything, when they're often the hardest alternative.

Comment: Your code doesn't contain a single line of JavaScript. Also, that seems to be markup for some undisclosed tool or library (Knockout?)

Comment: Thats code from the website of the HTML, I have my own JS code. I change the value of the ID by using document.getElementById('N6YFA53') but the ID changes each time I refresh the page So i want to change the value of the ID by matching the HTML name and then matching the name with the ID that is included in the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querySelector` to based on the input name then just use `id`.

```js
var first_name_id = document.querySelector("input[name='firstname']").id;

console.log(first_name_id);
```

```html
<input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="
    value: value,
    valueUpdate: 'keyup',
    hasFocus: focused,
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        'aria-describedby': getDescriptionId(),
        'aria-required': required,
        'aria-invalid': error() ? true : 'false',
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled
    }" name="firstname" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" id="N6YFA53">
```